# Hotlinking protecttion of only one directory

Tags: apache, hotlinking

I want to block access to only one directory say http://www.example.com/pictures
Every file in other directory should be available as normal.

I have gone through a referrer checking solution. That can be easily bypassed.

I Simply want to show images in pictures directory on a page say view.php
if images in this directory accessed from anywhere else. Just redirect to an image that says hotlinking not allowed"

Thanks

Comment: Applied this simple hotlinking prevention system "checking referer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have gone through a referrer checking solution. That can be easily bypassed.

Yes, it can. But so can any hotlink-prevention scheme. It'll deter casual/careless use, but that's about it.

For what it's worth, referrer-checking is pretty much the way to do it.

Comment: And what abt protecting only one directory ?

Comment: What webserver are you using? For Apache, this is easy with mod_rewrite: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-hotlinking . Note the comment about putting that `.htaccess` in the directory you want to protect